# How to count words by grouping similar words in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, word-count

I have a list

```
list_1 = ['warning', 'media', 'media-other','media-other','warning-type2','threat','threat-type1]
```

I need to count the occurrence of different types as in the following dictionary

```
dict_1 = {'warning':0, 'media':0, 'threat':0}
```

I need to select similar types and increase the count. `media` and `media-other` should be counted as `media`. `warning` and `warning-type2` should be counted as `warning`

The output of `dict_1` after counting should be `{'warning':2, 'media':3, 'threat':2}`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23909767/567595 for how to count items in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_1 = ['warning', 'media', 'media-other','media-other','warning-type2','threat','threat-type1']

list_2 = [x.split('-')[0] for x in list_1]
dict_1 = {}
for key in list_2:
    if key not in dict_1.keys():
        dict_1[key] = list_2.count(key)
print(dict_1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the part before any hyphen gives you the 'type' of the items in the list, you can use `split` and [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count them:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(word.split("-")[0] for word in list_1)
# returns  Counter({'warning': 2, 'media': 3, 'threat': 2})
```